# SCP within SSH'd directory

Tags: bash, unix, terminal

Suppose I have ssh'd into a directory ie

```
/u/.../directory
```

And I press `ls` and I see:

`file1.pdf file2.pdf file3.pdf`

Is it possible to SCP directly now?

Ie, `scp file2.pdf`?

Everytime I have done it like this: `scp .... ssh..... local dir`

Is there a better way?

Comment: The question is unclear: where do you want to `scp` that file to? Your command only specifies a source file, that does not make sense. And the final sketched flow turns around the order of commands. Also in the beginning the `/.../` does not make sense too... All in all: a vague question.

Comment: @arkascha, I want to SCP file1.pdf to my desktop, by `...` I meant generic directory path